# Extract 15 digit string from text using regex (re.findall) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, python-2.7

My input is--

```
Text = "My name is Alex , house no - 254456845 with mobile no. +91-11-22558845 and my account no. is - AB12569BF214558."
```

Now I want to use regex (re.findall) on my input text and get the expected output.

Expected Output= ( it contains both digits and alphabet and is always of length = 15 )

```
[ "AB12569BF214558" ]
```

please help

Comment: `Text[-15:]` maybe?

Comment: The duplicate link given is not, IMHO, enough because it doesn't include the exact regex logic/approach which is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the following regex pattern:

```
\b[A-Z0-9]{15}\b
```

This will ensure that you match a string of uppercase/numbers which is *exactly* 15 characters in length.  Sample script:

```py
Text = "My name is Alex , house no - 254456845 with mobile no. +91-11-22558845 and my account no. is - AB12569BF214558."
matches = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z0-9]{15}\b', Text)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['AB12569BF214558']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
results = re.findall('\\b[A-Z0-9]{15}\\b','''My name is Alex , house no - 254456845 with mobile no. +91-11-22558845 and my account no. is - AB12569BF214558.''')
```

Comment: this solution gives me my expected output in this case, but when i use this code in other cases then i gives me all the strings that have length 15 or more, i just want that string length should be strictly 15 only and not other string with length more than 15 should be given in output.

Comment: The {15} means exactly 15 characters. Fifteen or more would be {15,}

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you mean. The result is only 15 characters, but it is part of a longer string. Adding the '\b' at the start and end per Tim B's answer takes care of that.

Comment: @MukulKant Please don't mark code only answers like this. Otherwise you will get banned from reviewing.